# "post" keyword in Python source distribution filenames

Tags: python, setuptools

Can someone explain the following behavior to me?

```
$ python setup.py sdist
.........

$ls -l dist/
-rw-r--r--. 1 zenzic users 5.8K Oct 17 17:00 my_prog-3.0.3-20231017.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 zenzic users 6.0K Dec  9 19:48 my_prog-3.0.4.post20231209.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 zenzic users 5.9K Dec 11 15:15 my_prog-3.0.4-20231211.tar.gz
```

What causes the presence or absence of `post` in the filename?  I have not altered setup.cfg.  The only change to setup.py is the version number, and that doesn't *seem* to be causing the difference.  I'm sure there's an obvious explanation, but it's escaped me for a ridiculous length of time now. Thanks for any enlightenment you can shed!

Comment: Does [this](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/distribution.html#:~:text=A%20post%2Drelease,2.4%2D20051127.) answer your question?

Comment: Not really.  Why is my first build of version 3.0.4 denoted as a post-release while the second build, the real post-release (if I understand the concept) is not?  I understand the concept, but the behavior of setup.py is totally unpredictable to me here.  Experimentation yields no pattern I can discern.